# Is there a way to add/multiply aggregate functions in Microsoft Access using SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate, aggregate-functions

My goal is to have my Access query do as much math for me as possible. Is there was a way to add/mulitply(or in this cause divide) aggregate functions and display the output in a column?

Example:

```
SELECT   
SUM(dbo.tbl1.TYsales) AS TY, SUM(dbo.tbl1.LYsales) AS LY,
SUM(dbo.tbl1.TYsales) + SUM(dbo.tbl1.LYsales) AS [TY_LY], 
SUM(dbo.tbl1.LYsales) + SUM(dbo.tbl1.YBLsales) AS [LY_YBL] ,
SUM(TY_LY)/ SUM(LY_YBL)
```

I know this is probably far off. I am new to SQL and Access.

thank you

Comment: That will almost work. You can't normally refer to the calculated field again within the same query , without performing the aggregation again or using a sub query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because aggregations run at specific levels, you need to use a derived table or a second query that sources first aggregation. This is true of all databases given the set-based framework of tables:

```
SELECT SUM(TY_LY) / SUM(LY_YBL) AS final_result
FROM 
   (SELECT   
          SUM(dbo_tbl1_TYsales) AS TY, SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) AS LY,
          SUM(dbo_tbl1_TYsales) + SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) AS [TY_LY], 
          SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) + SUM(dbo_tbl1_YBLsales) AS [LY_YBL] ,
    FROM mytable) t
```

Alternatively with multiple queries:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT SUM(dbo_tbl1_TYsales) AS TY, SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) AS LY,
       SUM(dbo_tbl1_TYsales) + SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) AS [TY_LY], 
       SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) + SUM(dbo_tbl1_YBLsales) AS [LY_YBL]
FROM mytable
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT SUM(TY_LY) / SUM(LY_YBL) AS final_result
FROM Query1
```

---

And maybe, the Microsoft Access team will one day advance the JET/ACE SQL dialect (~quasi ANSI-1989) to current ANSI standards and implement CTEs (introduced in ANSI-1999) and even window functions (introduced in ANSI-2003).

**NOTE**: Below will *not* work in any MS Access version (posted as demo).

```
WITH cte AS
   (SELECT   
      SUM(dbo_tbl1_TYsales) AS TY, SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) AS LY,
      SUM(dbo_tbl1_TYsales) + SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) AS [TY_LY], 
      SUM(dbo_tbl1_LYsales) + SUM(dbo_tbl1_YBLsales) AS [LY_YBL] ,
    FROM mytable)

SELECT SUM(TY_LY) / SUM(LY_YBL)  AS final_result
FROM cte;
```

Comment: this makes much more sense, I am used to working with more object oriented programming and was lost when it comes to assigning values in SQL. 

thanks so much for the help!